# findByID is not a function

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

List item

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var Mongoose = require("Mongoose");

Mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/YelpCamp_app"); 

var YelpCampSchema = new Mongoose.Schema({
  name:String,
  image:String,
  description:String
});

var YelpCamp = Mongoose.model("YelpCamp",YelpCampSchema);

app.get('/campgrounds/:id',function(req,res){
  YelpCamp.findByID(req.params.id, function(err,campground) {
    if(err) {
      console.log("error");
    } else {
      res.render("show.ejs");
    }
  });
});
```

I am getting error that findByID is not a function

Comment: `var mongoose = require('mongoose')`. It's not a capital `M`.

Answer (score 3):

`findById` not `findByID`

```
app.get('/campgrounds/:id',function(req,res){
  YelpCamp.findById(req.params.id, (err,campground) => {
    if(err) {
      console.log("error");
    } else {
      res.render("show.ejs");
    }
  });
});
```

For more here: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#findbyid_findById

Answer (score 0):

You should require 'mongoose' instead of 'Mongoose'. After that you can Retrieving a single YelpCamp using findById like this:

```
var express = require("express");
    var app = express();
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/YelpCamp_app"); 
    const YelpCampSchema  = mongoose.Schema({
        name:String,
      image:String,
      description:String
    });
    var YelpCamp = mongoose.model("YelpCamp",YelpCampSchema);
    app.get('/campgrounds/:id',function(req,res){
    YelpCamp.findById(req.params.id)
        .then(data => {
            if(!data) {
                console.log("data not found");            
            }
            res.render("show.ejs");
        }).catch(err => {

          console.log("error");

        });
    });
```

Comment: What's the point of an answer that has zero explanation?  Are we supposed to guess what you changed?

Comment: @jfriend00 he changed what he say 'mongoose' instead of 'Mongoose'. Anyway the solution was findById not findByID as the answer of Truong Dang says